# Why does valgrind not show the obvious leaks in my program?

Tags: c, malloc, valgrind, free, cs50

As I was compiling a program in which I used malloc twice, I realised that I forgot to free the allocated memory at the end of the program.

Having recently encountered the Valgrind tool, I thought it would be a nice occasion to run it to see how it displays memory leaks errors. But to my surprise, Valgrind returned that all heaps blocks were freed...

[Valgrind results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fv0vv.png)

The only thing I can think of is that the mallocs were not in the main function but in a subordinate function. But I don't think that Valgrind would be restricted to main, would it

I have tried to find an answer in Valgrind documentation, but to no avail.

Here is the complete code as requested, the aim of which is to cipher a text thanks to a 26 letters key provided by the user as a command line argument.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void cipher(char *, char *);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./substitution key\n");
        return 1;
    }

    //INPUT
    char *p = get_string("plaintext: ");

    //OUTPUT
    cipher(argv[1], p);
    return 0;
}

void cipher(char *a, char *b)
{
    char *low = malloc(27 * sizeof(char));
    for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++)
    {
        if (islower(a[i]))
        {
            low[i] = a[i];
        }
        else
        {
            low[i] = (a[i] + 32);
        }
    }

    char *upp = malloc(27 * sizeof(char));
    for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++)
    {
        if (isupper(a[i]))
        {
            upp[i] = a[i];
        }
        else
        {
            upp[i] = a[i] - 32;
        }
    }

    printf("ciphertext: ");

    for (int i = 0, l = strlen(b); i < l; i++)
    {
        if (islower(b[i]))
        {
            printf("%c", low[(int)b[i]-97]);
        }
        else if (isupper(b[i]))
        {
            printf("%c", upp[(int)b[i]-65]);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%c", b[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What command line arguments did you use to invoke valgrind?

Comment: Please _edit_ your question and post _all_ your code. From what you _did_ post, you _should_ have a leak. I synthesized the remainder of your program and you _do_ have a memory that `valgrind` reported [here]: `definitely lost: 64 bytes in 3 blocks` Also, this appears to be `cs50` and the pointer returned by `get_string` is allocated, so you'd need `free` on that as well. _Side note:_ it's a bit moot because a better design can replace `upp` and `low` with `char upp[27];` and `char low[27];`, eliminating the `malloc`

Comment: Agreed, this needs a [mcve].  It could be, for instance, that compiler optimizations result in `malloc` not actually being called for certain inputs.  We need complete source code, exact input used, compiler version and options, and valgrind options.

Comment: To your question, no, `valgrind` is not limited to `main` and is supposed to track and report leaks for all `malloc` allocations, from whatever function.

Comment: It would improve the question to paste the lines visible in the image as text, instead of having the image

Comment: Valgrind tests the actual runtime behavior of your program.  Your C implementation is permitted to vary from the details expressed in the source code as long as it does not cause the externally observable behavior to change.  This freedom is most commonly used to implement optimizations.  Even though Valgrind reveals them to you, details of memory allocation and deallocation are not externally observable, as the language specification defines that term.

Comment: I find it entirely plausible that your compiler converts the small, fixed-size dynamic memory allocations of function `cipher()` into automatic allocations, as if of local variables.  Among the results would be that although source code analysis reveals a memory leak, that doesn't actually manifest at runtime.  You would need to examine the compiled code to verify.

Comment: @JohnBollinger So if I understand correctly your helpful comments, the minimal use I make of malloc in this program prevents memory leaks appearing in Valgrind's report thanks to the compiler's intervention. The only relatable analogy I have here would be that you don't necessarily get a seg fault when you slightly exceed an array's scope for instance, extra memory being allocated unbeknownst to you. I am not familiar with the concept of 'optimization' that keeps coming up in the comments so I have to look into that to better understand what's going on in this case.

Comment: @CraigEstey You are correct, this is a CS50 program so the use of malloc is somewhat artificial and the code may be sub-optimal in other ways as its role is mainly pedagogical. Nonetheless I thought it would be a good idea to test Valgrind as a debugging tool and was perplexed not to see the leaks reported.

Comment: @NateEldredge I have edited the question as requested and the answer seems indeed to lie with this concept of optimization. Not being familiar with it, I have to look further into it. I was aware of four steps in compiling: preprocessing, compiling, assembling and linking but had never heard about the compiler 'optimizing' the source code so that errors don't appear at runtime. That's a bit confusing but I'm sure it's for the best.

Comment: @Sam, perhaps a non-programming analogy would be more helpful.  Imagine that I want to have a new home built.  I give the builder detailed plans showing, among other things, paths for all the wire runs.  The builder puts all the electrical fixtures and outlets in the right locations, but routes the wire runs differently than my plans say. If an inspector looks at the original plans and finds code violations related to the wire runs, it may nevertheless be that the wire runs as actually laid conform to code -- whether that was the builder's motivation or not.

Comment: @JohnBollinger That makes sense. I had no idea that the compiler had so many degrees of freedom while translating the source code to machine code. Reading the wikipedia page on 'optimizing compilers' was quite eye-opening ! Here probably lies the reason why my memory leaks don't show up in Valgrind's report.

Comment: I tried compiling the code with a couple different compilers and options, but from looking at the assembly, couldn't see any indication that `malloc` had been optimized out.  That's why I'm asking for a complete test case: not only the program source, but also the specific compiler and version used, optimization options used, valgrind version and option, OS, and the input that triggers it.  (It might also be nice to adapt it to use stdio functions instead of cs50, to make it easier for people to test without installing that library.)

Comment: @NateEldredge I'll try and give you as much info as I can. The code was compiled on CS50 IDE, which is a cloud-based Ubuntu environment. The compiler used is clang, although I don't know if it runs the latest version. The Valgrind version is 3.15.0 (cf. the picture joined to my post). Hope this is constructive to pinpoint the issue.

Answer (score 1):

After all those comments, the answer is kind of silly...

Your screenshot shows you ran `valgrind ./substitution`, without passing any command line arguments to your program.  When this happens it prints `Usage: ./substitution key` and exits without doing anything further; in particular without calling `cipher()` and thus without ever calling `malloc()`.  So of course there is no memory leak in this case.

If you run the program with a key argument on the command line, and give it some input, you should see `valgrind` report the memory leak:

```
==15815== 
==15815== HEAP SUMMARY:
==15815==     in use at exit: 54 bytes in 2 blocks
==15815==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 2 frees, 2,102 bytes allocated
==15815== 
==15815== LEAK SUMMARY:
==15815==    definitely lost: 54 bytes in 2 blocks
==15815==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15815==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15815==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15815==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15815== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
```

Although in principle a compiler could optimize out the `malloc` calls, in my tests with gcc and clang with `-O3`, I couldn't find any indication of them actually doing so.

Comment: Gosh yes silly is indeed the right word to describe how I feel rn. I guess all this nevertheless made me aware of the concept of optimizing compilers, which I had never heard of before, so all is not lost. I'm apparently too much of a newbie to show a form of appreciation on this site, and I get it if that it's not in line with local rules, but I know what I feel for those who took some time to sort this out.